# Sphinx + MySql cp-1251

Tags: php, mysql, search, sphinx, cp1251

Настроил *сфинкс*, все работает, пока не вводишь в запрос поиска русские символы.

Сайт: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">`

MySql: `cp1251_general_ci`

sphinx.conf :

```
source product
{
    ...
    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES cp1251
    sql_query_pre = SET CHARACTER SET cp1251
}
...
index products
{
    charset_type = sbcs #  CP1251 тоже пробывал
    ...
}
```

По запросам с русским текстом вовсе ничего не возвращает в ответ.

Как исправить?

Comment: А почему не в UTF8?

Comment: @Vesper, байты бережет )))

Comment: База данных старая ей лет так 20 уже, теребить ее не хочется.
В течении года перееду на фреймверк YII2, а поиск нужен мол срочно.
Так что имеем что имеем...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Последние версии sphinx работают только с utf-8 кодировкой, и такой параметр как charset_type = sbcs недоступен.

Конфиг полечил так:

```
source product
{
    ...
    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES cp1251
    sql_query_pre = SET CHARACTER SET cp1251
    sql_query_pre = SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=utf8 # Добавил
}
...
index products
{
    <strike>charset_type = sbcs # Удалил
    ...
}
```

На стороне сервера, перекодировал данные в utf-8, так как сайт в widnwos-1251:

```
$query = iconv("CP1251", "UTF-8", $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

При индексации в sql запросах делать приведение к nvarchar.
select ID, cast(Name as nvarchar) as Name from ...
С учётом того, что последние вевсии сфинкса поддерживают только utf-8, это будет правильнее всего.

Comment: Какой эффект это даст? Можно подробнее?
У меня и так все отлично заработало...